# jquery check/uncheck list of checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Since upgrading to jquery 1.9 my script stopped working for checking/unchecking checkboxes.

I have a main check box that controls selecting/checking a list of checkboxes in a table. After upgrading to new jquery version only initially clicking "Check all" checkboxes get selected. Clicking the second time "Check all" causes checkboxes to uncheck, BUT doing "Check all" click after 2 clicks table checkboxes cease to work anymore.

[image]

script:

```
    $("#itemsList .checkall").on("click", function () {
        $(".checkbox").attr("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
```

also tried this:

```
    $("#itemsList .checkall").click(function () {
        $(".checkbox").attr("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
```

html "Check all":

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" name="checkall" class="checkbox checkall">
```

html table checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox">
```

this used to work just fine before switching to jquery 1.9.
what gives??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.6 for changing properties of elements `prop` method should be used instead of `attr`.

```
$("#itemsList .checkall").on("change", function () {
     $(".checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: this works. thanks. why did it work before with old jquery version?

Comment: @ShaneKm You are welcome, because `checked` attribute is mapped to a property(after being set) and `attr` doesn't change the properties.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead since:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

```
$("#itemsList .checkall").on("change", function () {
    $(".checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```